# Filter numpy structured array based based on unique elements in one dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

So I have a rather large (200k+ rows) structured array:

```
recordtype = np.dtype([('x',np.float32),('y',np.float32),('z',np.float32), \
                       ('u',np.float32),('v',np.float32),('w',np.float32), \
                       ('d',np.float32),('T',np.float32),('mdot',np.float32), \
                       ('f',np.float32),('t',np.float32),('name',np.str_,14)])
data = np.loadtxt('tmp2.out',dtype=recordtype,skiprows=2)
```

In the 'name' columns, there are non-unique elements: `len(data[:]['name'])` is larger than `len(set(data[:]['name']))`. I would like to create a new array with only unique elements from  `name`, I guess first occurrence is fine. How would I do this efficiently?

Comment: You don't need `data[:]['name']`, just `data['name']` will do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to get unique indices you can use np.unique

```
unique_elements, indices = np.unique(data[:]['name'], return_index = True)
```

then you know the unique indices in the name dimension that you need to access.  Then you should be able to do just select those indices

```
data = data[indices]
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew there must have been something built-in somewhere to get the indices but I somehow missed it.